# LyX: Url not showing in references using natbib and url packages

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, urls

I know there are many questions posted about this topic and that my question might be a duplicate (I'm a beginner in LyX, so apologizing in advance). However, I preformed a search before posting but I haven't been able to find one that seems to match my problem.

I am using unsrt natbib style that supports urls (I have checked the .bst) and the entries in my bib file have the url. However, the url is not being displayed in my pdf.

Additional info, I am generating the bib file with Zotero using Western encoding.

Bib file entry example:

```
@misc{noauthor_interconnect_nodate,
        titlenter code heree = {{INTERCONNECT} {Circuit} {Solver} {\textbar} {Lumerical} {Inc}},
        url = {https://www.lumerical.com/support/whitepaper/interconnect_circuit_solver.html},
        urldate = {2018-03-05},
}
```

My LaTeX preamble is:

```
%{{ Don't change! times font for proper scaling
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[scaled=.90]{helvet}
\usepackage{courier}
%}} times font for proper scaling

\usepackage[numbers,square]{natbib} %see http://merkel.zoneo.net/Latex/natbib.php for usage!
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{xtab, tabularx} %for multipage tables
\usepackage[Sonny]{fncychap} %for the chapter headings
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{float}

%{{ set double-space
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing
%}} set double-space

%set margins
\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1in, left=1.25in, right=1.25in]{geometry}

% Define your own commands and environment definitions, for example:
\newcommand{\program}[1]{\textbf{#1}} % program names in bold text
\newcommand{\exten}[1]{\texttt{#1}} % file extensions in bold text (use caps)
\newcommand{\cmmd}[1]{\textbackslash\texttt{#1}} % command name in tt font
\newcommand{\enviro}[1]{\texttt{#1}} % environment name in tt font  
\newenvironment{definition}[1]{\begin{quote}\emph{#1}:}{\end{quote}}
  % Provides indented formal definition and emphasizes the word.
  % e.g. \begin{definition}{Reliability} ... \end{definition}

% Put the document title and page numbers in the header
\pagestyle{headings}
\pagenumbering{roman}

%Place floats within section
\usepackage[section]{placeins}

% To be able to capitalize cross reference
\usepackage{cleveref}
```

Comment: Use `howpublished` instead of url. -> `howpublished = {\url{<URL here>},`

Comment: By the way, you should have a look at https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliographies_with_biblatex_and_biber

Comment: Is there a way to change all the url to howpublished other than by hand? I have a long bibliography.

Comment: If you switch to the modern biblatex, there is no need to change anything. It supports `url`  as well as `urldate`. Your reference management tool seems to be in biblatex mode already. It also provides `online` instead of `misc` for your online entries. Find out more by clicking the link i posted earlier.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with LyX.

Comment: I disagree that the information that I'm using LyX is not relevant, even though the underlying problem is not just LyX related.
The solution and how it is implemented depends on the environment I'm using.